# How to encrypt shipped database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption

Team,

I have an Android application with large SQLite database this data costs me lots of money and I don't want to let anybody have it easily.
This database come to me as databse.sqlite file and I shipped into into the APK assets.

is there anyway to encrypt this database before shipping and then decrypt while reading the data ?

P.S I searched for this a lot and all of my results point me to use sqlcipher but this lib does not work with shipped SQLite database file.

Comment: hackers will spend 15 minutes to decrypt it. Keep it on a server if your data is very valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you will need to store the key (or location of the key) somewhere in your code and deodexing the application doesn't take that much effort. Unfortunately, you can't really prevent anyone from accessing the data. You can only make it harder, but it will still be pretty easy for someon who is really determined.

The best solution would be to store the database on a server and only send the data the user actually needs to the device. That way you have at least some control over what data a device requests.

Comment: I still need to store the data on the device for offline viewing !

Comment: also the problem with the shipped database ! its inside the APK !

Comment: Is this actually your data or is the DB purchased from a third party? If it is your data, maybe you can pack it in some form that better suits your needs. If it is from a third party, why do you care if they access it? You won't get any harm from it.

Comment: its my data .. I spend some time and money to collect this data.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind would actually be one of the most complicated ones. I had a similar case where we used a heavily customized open-source c++ database system that had no wide-spread support like SQLite. That way anyone wanting to get the data would need to write his own reader first. That would make it very tedious, but still not impossible, to crack the database. I would still use a server-based approach and just let the app fail if there is no connection. In my experience most users are fine with the fact that their phone isn't half as useful without data connection.